# Parse a tile map into efficient horizontal and vertical bounding boxes

Tags: c++, arrays, math, stdvector

I'm working on a simple platformer game in C++, everything is working great except i want to group tiles into bounding boxes in order to have less passes of the physics function(i'm targeting both PC's and embedded devices so its all about speed).

What the following function does is load a simple map format:
"[char *header][char bytesize][bytesize w][bytesize h][char tw][char th][char *map]"
It then reads the array as a 2d map and groups vertical lines when possible.

The question is... could someone *show* me how to group these tiles into efficient bounding boxes on both vertical and horizontal axis?

Heres an image to help explain, i know my grammar and spelling is terrible: http://thetooth.name/dev/blocks_bic.png

```
    void Environment::load_map(char* mapPath){
        cl("Loading Map: %s ", mapPath);

        FILE* mapFile = fopen(mapPath, "rb");
        FILE* mapInfoFile = fopen(strcat(substr(mapPath, 0, strlen(mapPath)-3), "bmd"), "rb");

        if (mapFile == NULL || mapInfoFile == NULL)
        {
            cl("[ERROR]\n");
            throw KLGLException("Error loading map file!");
            return;
        }

        size_t wordSize;
        char tBuffer[8] = {};
        int w = 0;
        int h = 0;
        int tileWidth = 0;
        int tileHeight = 0;

        fread(tBuffer, 1, 7, mapFile);
        if (strcmp(tBuffer, "STME1.0"))
        {
            cl("[BADHEADER]");
        }

        fill_n(tBuffer, 8, NULL);
        fread(tBuffer, 1, 1, mapFile);
        if (!strcmp(tBuffer, "B"))
        {
            wordSize = sizeof(char);
        }else{
            wordSize = sizeof(int);
        }

        fseek(mapFile, 8, SEEK_SET);
        fread(&w, wordSize, 1, mapFile);
        fread(&h, wordSize, 1, mapFile);
        fread(&tileWidth, 1, 1, mapFile);
        fread(&tileHeight, 1, 1, mapFile);

#define lvLookup y*w+x
        fill_n(mapData, (w*h)+1, '\0');
        fill_n(mapMask, (w*h)+1, '\0');

        // Read files into memory... back to front and inside out...
        for(int y = 0; y < h; y++){
            for(int x = 0; x < w; x++){
                fread(&mapData[lvLookup], 1, 1, mapFile);
                fread(&mapMask[lvLookup], 1, 1, mapInfoFile);
            }
        }

        fclose(mapFile);
        fclose(mapInfoFile);

        // Parse map data into are geometry vectors
        for(int x = 0; x < w; x++){
            for(int y = 0; y < h; y++){
                if(mapData[lvLookup] > 0){
                    int xl = x;
                    int yl = y;
                    while(mapData[yl*w+x] != 0/* && mapMask[yl*w+x] == 0*/){
                        yl++;
                    }
                    platforms->push_back(Platform(x*tileWidth, y*tileHeight, 1*tileWidth, (yl-y)*tileHeight, lvLookup, mapData, mapMask));
                    y = yl-1;
                }
            }
        }
        cl("[OK]\n");
    }
```

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: What do the white lines going to various corners in the illustration signify? Could you give a simple example or two of what kind of output you expect?

Comment: the white lines are from the top left to the bottom right of the boxes, its showing what would happen if a tile was missing(the green block)

Comment: So in the second case you want the resulting platforms to span [ ((0,0),(0,3)), ((0,4), (0,8)), ((1,0),(8,8)) ] or something like that?

Comment: yeah, the idea is to keep vertical walls when ever possible, but to also optimize out long horizontal flats providing they don't compromise the first rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a little ugly, but I think it should work as a starting point. It works by scanning left to right, top to bottom looking for to find whole columns that are alike. The challenging part is keeping track of consecutive complete vertical blocks and outputting "partial" runs correctly.

```
void find_bounds()
{
    int startx = 0;
    char last = mapData[0];
    for (int x = 0; x < w; x++) {
        int starty = 0;
        for (int y = 0; y < h; y++) {
            char c = mapData[x+y*w];
            if (c != last) {
                if (starty == 0) {
                    // finish last run of complete vertical blocks
                    if(startx != x) { 
                        // it ran more than one column, output those first
                        span(last, startx, 0, x-1, h-1);
                        startx = x;
                    }
                    // and a run from the start of this column
                    span(last, x, 0, x, y);
                } else {
                    // a run within a column
                    span(last, x, starty, x, y);
                }
                last = c;
                starty = y;
            }
        }
        // had a run withing this column or processing last column, finish it up
        if (starty || x == w-1) {
            span(last, x, starty, x, h-1);
            startx= x + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Test-suite (the first two should correspond to the second and third cases from your illustration):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

const int w = 8, h = 8;
char mapData[w*h+1] = 
#if 1
"xxxxxxxx"
"xxxxxxxx"
"xxxxxxxx"
" xxxxxxx"
"xxxxxxxx"
"xxxxxxxx"
"xxxxxxxx"
"xxxxxxxx"
#elif 0
"xxxxxxxx"
"xxxxxxxx"
"xxx xxxx"
"xxxxxxxx"
"xxxxxxxx"
"xxxxxxxx"
"xxxxxxxx"
"xxxxxxxx"
#else
"xxxxxxxx"
"xx xxxxx"
"xxxxxxxx"
"xx xxxxx"
"xxxx xxx"
"xxxxxxxx"
"xxxxxxxx"
"xxxxxxxx"
#endif
;

void span(char type, int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1)
{
    if (!(x0 == x1 && y0 == y1))
        cout << type << " " << x0 << ", " << y0 << " ->  " << x1 << ", " << y1 << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    find_bounds();
}
```

Comment: thank you, works great!, now its just a matter of implementing slopes and my game will be finished ^D^